# Adding vertical line (equal sign) to augmented bmatrix WITHOUT using array

Tags: matrices, rules

Is there a way to add a vertical line (equal sign) to an augmented `bmatrix` (4x4) WITHOUT using `array`? Any help provided would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Could you post some code, or at least a scan of a hand-drawn sketch of what you're looking to achieve?

Comment: @Mico: See the screenshot below from Steven, that is what I am trying to achieve but because I am using an application that does not support the use of array, I cannot use array to achieve it.

Answer (score 18):

No, you have to use `array`, because the `amsmath` matrix environments don't provide for specifying rules.

```
\left[\begin{array}{@{}ccc|c@{}}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4
\end{array}\right]
```

The trick for emulating `bmatrix` (or `pmatrix`) is having `@{}` at both ends.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what `@{}` means?

Comment: @Eric “Don't add the usual padding”

Comment: This still doesn't quite work for me. [The one on the left uses `bmatrix`, the other `{array}{@{}c@{}}`](https://imgur.com/a/3GJGU). `\hline` seems to behave differently in the two cases

Comment: You actually want `\left[\hskip -\arraycolsep ... \hskip -\arraycolsep\right]`, and to omit the `@{}` (determined by looking at [`amsmath.sty`](http://www.csee.ogi.edu/support/unix/latex/inputs/amsmath.sty))

Comment: @Eric No, why should I? Do you doubt I know the code in `amsmath`? It's there in order to solve a very different problem. Of course, `\hline` was not requested. Otherwise, yes, the code like in `amsmath` can help. But that's *partitioned matrices*, there are questions about them on the site.

Comment: _"No, why should I?"_ - because that is how you exactly emulate `bmatrix`. `@{}` is just an approximation. But in this case, you're right - what you have is sufficient. And no, the link was not for your benefit, but for any passers by :)

Answer (score 14):

Here I use `bmatrix`, but have created `\aug` to be a vertical strut that can be placed between columns.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\aug{\fboxsep=-\fboxrule\!\!\!\fbox{\strut}\!\!\!}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 &\aug& 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 &\aug& 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 &\aug& 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 &\aug& 4
\end{bmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for responding but the application I am using does not support \aug either. There is not a complete and current list of the items supported by the application so I am going by trial and error.

Comment: @TechEng Too bad.  I gather you are unable to add LaTeX `\newcommand`s to your existing application?

Comment: No, I am not. It is very limited. I can get the matrix using             \begin{bmatrix} x & x & x & x\\ \end{bmartix}, I just have not found a way to add the vertical line.

Comment: @TechEng, Could you use `\def\aug` instead of `\newcommand\aug`?

Comment: No, \def\aug does not work either. It is very limited in what will work. I can make it work graphically by adding an image on top but I was hoping to get the equation to work by itself. I appreciate your time. I will just keep trying other things.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes, how can we port `\aug` to use with `bsmallmatrix`?

Comment: @Ashirwad Maybe this: `\newcommand\aug{\fboxsep=-\fboxrule\!\smash{\fbox{\scriptsize\mathstrut}}\!}`

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes, it doesn't seem to work quite right. I have put your code on Overleaf, so you can try making changes here: https://www.overleaf.com/2572135168vrgkpzyygkzg and post the workable answer.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes, my bad, I didn't load the `mathtools` package in the preamble! It now works fine with `bsmallmatrix`, but now I see gaps between vertical struts in `bmatrix`! So, you may still want to check the link. :D Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Ashirwad I do not get the gap you speak of, but you could always replace the `\fbox` with an explicit `\rule` in the manner of `\newcommand\aug{\!\smash{\rule[-1pt]{.7pt}{7pt}}\!}`, adjusting the rule values if needed.

Comment: Ok. I am sharing the read-only link. It won't ask you to log in: https://www.overleaf.com/project/5e8bde42ce7d6a0001126d0c I see it here! But anyways, I will try out your recommendation.

Answer (score 9):

For those who may still be searching for an answer.
You can actually make an augmented matrix with two matrices inside delimiters of your choice:

```
\left[
  \begin{matrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 \\
    1 & 2 & 3 \\
    1 & 2 & 3 \\
    1 & 2 & 3 \\
  \end{matrix}
  \left|
    \,
    \begin{matrix}
      4  \\
      4  \\
      4  \\
      4  \\
    \end{matrix}
  \right.
\right]
```

This code produces a matrix like this: 
[image: Matrix example]

You can modify space between delimiters by adding `\,` or other spacers.

Comment: Not my preferred way, but at least it's easy to input. The `\left|` should better be `\;\middle|\;` (removing `\right.`).

Comment: +1 searching for a solution that works on mac Pages since forever and only this answer works

Comment: This has the added niceness of aligning perfectly with the definition of an augmented matrix $\left(A\;\middle|\;B\right)$ of $A$ and $B.$

Answer (score 1):

Using the package `spalign` you can get the answer faster with the command `\spalignaugmat{}`. Here within of this command the blank spaces between the elements of the matrix are important.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{spalign}
\begin{document}
\[ \spalignaugmat{1 2 3 4; 1 2 3 4; 1 2 3 4; 1 2 3 4;} \]
\end{document}
```

[image]