# How to add either dashed or colored vertical line in array, but without using `arydshln`?

Tags: arrays

I need to make what is called augmented matrix, using `array`. This requires a vertical line added before the last column.

Using answer in [adding-vertical-line-equal-sign-to-augmented-bmatrix-without-using-array](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/299221/adding-vertical-line-equal-sign-to-augmented-bmatrix-without-using-array)
show hows to add vertical line. Here is the answer:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\[
\left[\begin{array}{@{}ccc|c@{}}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4
\end{array}\right]
\]
\end{document}
```

Which works well. I just like to have the vertical line, either dashed or colored say red, to make it more clear.

[image]

**I can not use** `arydshln` as this package breaks many things. It does not work when loading longtable for example, and it does not work with tex4ht.

But array on its own, works. I just do not know how to add macro either inplace or in the preamble to tell it to make that one vertical line be dashed, or different color.  I prefer answer that does not use tikz also, just to keep it simple.  I would like the answer to work both in lualatex and tex4ht if possible, as I compile same source code to PDF and HTML.

But if it works only in PDF (i.e using lualatex), that will be fine also.

TL 2020

Comment: Easiest is probably using `tikzmark`.  I'm sure we have plenty of duplicates around the side.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a solution for a coloured vertical rule:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{xcolor, array, bigstrut}

\begin{document}
\[
\left[\begin{array}{@{}ccc!{\color{red}\vline width 0.6pt}c@{}}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \bigstrut[t]\\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4
\end{array}\right]
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

The package `nicematrix` provides a specifier `:` for vertical dotted lines. The package loads PGF.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}    
\usepackage{nicematrix, bigstrut}    
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{bNiceArray}{ccc:c}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \bigstrut[t]\\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4
\end{bNiceArray}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]